# Typescript: Ensure that function returns correct type depending on interface key

Tags: typescript

How can I type this so that it errors unless the returned value of `price: t => t.price` is a number (according to `UData`'s interface):

```
// The prop value can be null, or a function which returns the 
// correct type (not `any`)
type PropTable<T, U> = Record<keyof U, null | ((t: T) => any)>

//
// Example use
//

interface TData {
    price: string
}

interface UData {
    price: number
}

// Should fail as the returned type is a string and "price" in 
// UData requires a number.
const props1: PropTable<TData, UData> = {
    price: t => t.price
}

// Should work as the returned type is a number which "price" in 
// UData requires.
const props2: PropTable<TData, UData> = {
    price: t => Number(t.price)
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUAsFNQBwE4Hs6gG4EMA2BXWBjDAO1ACNYicssAaUJBUDUAMxyPwBcBLJEgd0jd8kUAmiccCIgGdQnGKHwNxXeQE84sABREknUAANi6wwEoAUJ02wACsjjgMpLNAA84OgFUAfKAC8oABK0MoIACZuANbQ6kgsoF50lNSgAD6g2tqcAFwQZgF+JmY+FhYg5WAAogAeGAC2cK6gODLQlWXcRJzQCCwY+LDgACIYnMwA3hagM-AIwtB5MpzzRADmFgC+nd29-YOJo+OgU7NzC3mU9eQIW2UgoADKkEhU4awY3FhMcgqw4pJpNB3tYtKBuHJmMtVmsmER3gAiRALBHgkheI7McQARxw3HEkNAVxuADoLMpZAZECgZABGPL2FBOFzuEZjDDeTF+QKnWbIwZ5Az+PycEn89rbSpPF5vUD8BhRH7yRQAqREYEaMEQphEnDXXpyoQiUBI+aDVFdQ7ssTQXH46AyMkU5ZzGkAJgZDmZrg8mM57O5J2mfLNi3khVAADk9TdsmLQ5ZtkA)

Comment: The playground link is broken...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the solution here is to use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
type PropTable<T, U> = {
    [key in keyof U]: null | ((t: T) => U[key])
}
```

Comment: Don't you need `U extends Record<keyof T, any>`?

Comment: @JasonKleban it doesn't need to extend that specific record, but TypeScript does behave oddly when `U` is a primitive type. For example, it incorrectly infers that `PropTable<string, number>` is equivalent to `number`: [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEsDsGMHsCd4FNoBcKQGZOTJAoVATwAclQAFeWEgFQEMAjAGyQB5aAaUAVQD5QAXlABvfKAmgA2gGskRDKDlFYmXgF0AXKEgBXZs1AAfUAApTqbbQCUQgT1nz11-AF98cSAGd0AD21UNAws7D7wUADm3HoAtow4AsIArADc+CCgcIgo6FDYuNAEnj6gRNoi0sqKyqo6unE4WnUGxmYW2mGRtoICsfHwjkTOoK5CoKn4QA)